# Python: Printing figures from file is getting slower and slower

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-itertools

I have a large file (~10 GB) which contains t = 1000 (n x n)-matrices where n = 1000. The data file contains float numbers. I wrote a program which prints every matrix as a .png image. The problem is, that it gets slower and slower. The first image needs less than a second to print. Image 350 needs more than 2 minutes! The plot below shows the problem for t = 27 matrices / images.

[image]

Here is my code I use. Does someone see why it is getting slower and slower?

```
import itertools as it
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

def printImage(M, k):
    fig = plt.imshow(M, interpolation='nearest')
    fig.set_cmap('hot')
    fig.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    fig.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.savefig(str(k) + '.png', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0, dpi=300)

    plt.ioff()

n = 1000
t = 1000

with open('data', 'r') as f:
    for i in range(t):
        t0 = time.clock()
        try:
            items = [list(map(float, i.split())) for i in it.islice(f, n)]
        except:
            raise
        else:
            printImage(items,i)
        t1 = time.clock()
        print(str(i) + '/' + str(t) + ' ' + str(t1-t0))
```

Comment: It looks like you are saving the exact same image 1000 times, or why would `it.islice(f, n)` be different for different loop cycles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is probably because you're not closing your figures, which consumes more and more memory.

Modify your plotting to read

```
import itertools as it
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

def printImage(M, k):
    figobj = plt.figure()
    fig = plt.imshow(M, interpolation='nearest')
    fig.set_cmap('hot')
    fig.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    fig.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.savefig(str(k) + '.png', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0, dpi=300)
    plt.close(figobj)
```

You probably don't need the call to `plt.ioff` either.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: Thanks for the catch - the OP's unusual choice of variable name (`fig` for the imshow object) threw me off

Comment: @jmets What would be a better choice for the variable names? Why do I need `figobj`? I thought that `fig` is the same as `figobj`? What is the difference?

Comment: Call a figure `fig`, call an `imshow` image `image`. You can easily find out the return type by printing `print(fig)` or `print(type(fig))` (same with the image). As a result you will see that a figure is a figure and an image is an image.